# How to cache variables in the Event System

Tags: event-system

I have an event that retrieves information from Publication Metadata.  I would like to cache this information so that I don't need to access the Publication object each time.  I see that the ContextVariables allow me to pass information between events.  Can I use this for caching?  If not, any alternative ways to cache information to re-use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use a static Dictionary in a config class. I think (at least in 2013+ versions) that this should persist for the lifetime of the parent CMS process (typically core service, but could be publisher etc.). Context variables are probably only persisting for the execution of a (chain of) event(s), so will be wiped between separate actions that trigger new events

Comment: A static Dictionary is a nice one, I mostly use readonly variables which I set in the constructor, see my [ECL Stub Component Event Handler](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/ECL%20Stub%20Component%20Event%20Handler/trunk/ECL%20Stub%20Component%20Event%20Handler/EventHandler.cs)