# Fire Tridion Event extension when user logs in

Tags: event-system, user-management

I want to capture user information when the page loads. Created event extension for same but event is getting triggered many time which is impacting the performance of our system. I only want event to be triggered only once when page loads.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain your event extension in more detail, and also include a code sample?  Is it a GUI Extension or Event System?  For example,  if it is a GUI Extension you have the option to target a specific view in the GUI.  Thanks.

Comment: Purpose of my event system is to get last login date for users. I am able to get the last login date for user but whenever user object is loaded it is firing the event system again again which is impacting performance.I dont want event system to be called everytime user object loads instead i want it to be called when CME loads

Comment: I wanted to do a similar thing.  Check this question and answer.  Would be nice to post your solution code as the answer to this question if it manages to solve your problem, as it would be helpful for people in the future.  Thanks!  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-cache-variables-in-the-event-system